# How do I connect a pgAdmin Docker container to Postgres running on local machine (non-container)?

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I'm running pgAdmin in a docker container, trying to connect to Postgres running locally on my machine. No matter what IP address I enter, it gives an error saying :

"Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

My server is indeed running, and it is allowing external addresses (listen_addresses = '*').

I guess I'm just not using the correct IP address. What is the correct address I should use?

Here is my docker compose code:

```
version: '3'

services:
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: me@me.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
      network_mode: host
  
restart: unless-stopped
```

[pgAdmin screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAhdf.png)

Comment: What OS you use?

Comment: I'm using MacOS

Answer (score 0):

if you use Linux try set `172.17.0.1` to host

Or `host.docker.internal` on windows https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds

Mac `host.docker.internal` https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds

Comment: I'm on a Mac, but it didn't work. Same error.

Comment: try without ```network_mode: host```

Comment: Tried w/out network_mode; same issue. Won't allow "host.docker.internal" either. It wants a literal address